# Boundedness of a simple differential equation's solution

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

I have a simple problem that I encountered when I was trying to prove the boundedness of a function created from a smooth manifold. The problem is simplified to the next general statement:
Let $f:(-\infty,\infty)\to (-\infty,\infty)$ be a bounded, $C^{\infty}$-class function.
Suppose $\frac{d^nf}{dt^n}<\infty$ for any $n=1,2,...$. Then, is the function below bounded from above?
$$
g(x)=\int_0^x\left(\frac{df}{dt}\right)^3dt,\quad x\in[0,\infty).
$$
If the function is monotonically increasing, the answer is "yes" since if we let $|f|<N_0$ and $\left|\frac{df}{dt}\right|<N_1$, then
$$
g(x)\le N_1^2\int_0^x\left|\frac{df}{dt}\right|dt=N_1^2\int_0^x\frac{df}{dt}dt=N_1^2(f(x)-f(0))\le 2N_1^2N_0.
$$
I can't figure out if the statement is true when $f$ is not monotonical. I am a student in the field of differential geometry so any advice would be great.

Comment: @lutz-lehmann As stated, the argument proposed in the question is valid for non-decreasing functions, in which case you indeed have $|f'| = f'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer is that $g$ can be unbounded.**

Let us consider $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ which is $1$-periodic. In particular, all its derivatives are uniformly bounded.
Then, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, you will have
$$
g(n) = \int_0^n (f')^3 = n \int_0^1 (f')^3
$$
so $g$ is unbounded if we can find a $1$-periodic function such that $\int_0^1 (f')^3 \neq 0$.

We will actually choose $f(x) = \phi(x)$ for $x \in (0,1)$ where $\phi$ is smooth and compactly supported in $(0,1)$. Thus, it is clear that the extension by periodicity to $\mathbb{R}$ will be smooth because all derivatives are null and thus match at the junction points.

So now we need to construct such a $\phi$. Let us start with some $\psi \in C^\infty_c((0,1);\mathbb{R})$ such that $\int_0^1 \psi = 0$ and $\int_0^1 \psi^3 = 1$. Then we can set $\phi(x) := \int_0^x \psi$.

Comment: This proof seems that it can be done when we want to prove that $h(x)=\int_0^x \frac{df}{dt}dt$ is not bounded. However, here $h(x)$ is bounded because $h(x)=f(x)-f(0)$. I can't figure out where you used the fact that we are taking the integral of the "3rd" power of $\frac{df}{dt}$.

Comment: Nice comment! The point is that it would not be possible to construct a **compactly supported in (0,2)** $\phi$ such that $\int_0^2 \phi' = 1$ (because, as you noted, we would need $\int_0^2 \phi' = \phi(2) - \phi(0) = 0 - 0 = 0$). So you just need to convince yourself that one can indeed construct a compactly supported $\phi$ such that $\int (\phi')^3 \neq 0$.

Comment: I updated my answer (twice). Now the construction should be more obvious and the compatibility of the constraints more visual.